# How to Dynamically Create and Populate Word Document Templates with Form Data?

Tags: microsoft-word, javascript, forms, document-automation

### Preface

I’m working on a project where I need to digitize the form filling process for a testing lab company. The company currently fills out forms manually and makes 40 copies of each form. The form itself is obscenely large (138 pages, 300+ input fields). The forms are then given to a tester who jots down his observations. All of the results are combined back into a result form which is then digitized, printed, and sent to the government. It is imperative that the format is preserved.

The form name is [IEC 62368-1](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/85813) (I have attached an Image as I could not find a web downloadable version). There is a Data sheet and a Test Report by the lab, but all of this process needs to be digitized. I want to create a system where the forms can be filled out digitally, and the data from these forms is used to populate a Word document template. This Word document is then saved and can be printed or sent digitally.

Here’s an example of the data sheet:

#### **62368-1 Test Data Sheet**

[image: Image of Test Data Sheet]

And here’s an example of the corresponding report sheet:

[image: Test Report Sheet]

I want to create a system where a user can fill out a form (either an HTML form or a Microsoft Form), and the data from this form is used to populate a Word document template. The Word document should maintain the same formatting as the original document. The placeholders in the Word document should be added by the program.

### Additional Challeges and Preferences

1. The form needs to be in printable condition which raises the following issues:
2. Handling images when stitching back the document

   - these fields need to be resized in order to fit the image size on paper [image: Images]
3. Microsoft Stack is Preferred as the company deals in Microsoft Products. ( PowerApps, Azure OpenAI/ Document Intelligence)
4. The solution I have in mind is that I generate 2 templates each (Test Report and Data Sheet) which is filled by a form (Microsoft Form or a custom Form) and then using Microsoft Automate/Flows this data is sent into an azure function which aggregates all data sheet observations from multiple testers and does some processing and enters into the test report.
   The Test Report template would resize itself according to the input from the processed Azure Function (Image Fields would expand to the size and images can shrink to fit). Because of the template the layout would be preserved, and Azure functions can take care of the size fields. User will only need to upload Blank Data Sheets and Test Reports, which will be stored on their SharePoint with the processed files that I discussed above. The Manager would be notified when the processed files are available for download.

### What I've Tried

- I’ve tried using [docxtemplater](https://docxtemplater.com/docs/installation/) to create and populate the Word document, but I’m having trouble adding the placeholders to the Word document. I’m also not sure how to maintain the formatting of the original document.
- I have also tried Microsoft Forms into Word, but Forms has a character limit which this easily crosses (200 questions per form).
- I tried the Word Developer tab -> Microsoft Word Forms but then I would need to label 300 questions across 40 forms which is not at all possible
- The One thing that works almost perfectly is Adobe Forms and automatic labelling. It needs some input from the user, but it does most of it, which is the kind of result I am expecting but as its closed source I cannot resize Image input fields with custom JavaScript (which adobe can run)

Is there a way to do this using JavaScript or any AI service? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: These may assist you or help get you started: http://www.gmayor.com/ExtractDataFromForms.htm and https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/extract_batch_form_data.html. Note these are vba resources, not JS nor AI.

Comment: I wasn't in a position to get the form but Re. Labelling 300 questions across 40 forms with content controls you can insert the controls manually while creating the forms templates then label them programmatically.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I would need to test the effectiveness of the method and I'll revert with results when I can. Also, I want to clarify _that the word file_ is **not so structured**, it's using **various different word elements** (`ellipsis` to show blanks, `tables` for structured data, and images) so **it's not a proper form**, but your method indicates it works for forms.

Comment: @jonsson Good idea, I actually thought of it myself. I would need to make class structure to detect elements (`ellipsis', 'tables` and `images`) and then I would need to transform them into html elements (with labels) or replace them (in place) with word form elements (with labels).

This does require a lot of manual effort which I am willing to do but not before I research a better way.

Comment: @jonsson 

I can attach a minified version of the word document (from google drive, onedrive as a link) if it would help in my question itself?

Comment: @jonsson adding to my previous answer, even if I do manage to label and enter all data, there is no way I can estimate the dimensions of the fields (printable) and expand them beforehand

Comment: @Lucifer TBH I was really only attempting a response to a tiny piece of the whole scenario you present. I've re-read what you posted and your comments. To me, the starting point is "what do you have to use to collect your data" - is it an HTML page of some kind, or could it be a Word document with content controls? If it's the latter, it's not obvious to me why you would be stuck with several kinds of data input field in Word - i.e. is something stopping you from moving away from those ellipses etc. and creating a completely new Word document that just used one type of input?

Comment: @jonsson I think you're closer to the question now. It's the latter but the there is no actual controls, just tables and text. It's the scale of it that moves me away from making a custom program. I can code it out, but I needed to know if there is any solution that already offers what I am about to code. Also, any direction as to how would be of great help too.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I'm just not familiar enough with some of the more modern bits (Automate+, Flows and so on) to make useful suggestions at a "bigger picture" level. Broadly speaking from a long term perspective, if you need to do coding at a "VBA" level you'll probably be better off actually using Office-JS as it's where Microsoft has been heading for several years already.

Comment: @jonsson Microsoft JS , that I would love! VBA is uhhh cumbersome right now for me

.Did you mean [this?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.